# Loop from one integer to another regardless of direction, with minimal overhead

Tags: c++, algorithm

Assume I'm given two unsigned integers:

```
size_t A, B;
```

They're loaded out with some random numbers, and A may be larger, equal, or smaller than B.  I want to loop from A to B.  However, the comparison and increment both depend on which is larger.

```
for (size_t i = A; i <= B; ++i) //A <= B
for (size_t i = A; i >= B; --i) //A >= B
```

The obvious brute force solution is to embed these in if statements:

```
if (A <= B)
{
 for (size_t i = A; i <= B; ++i) ...
}
else
{
 for (size_t i = A; i >= B; --i) ...
}
```

Note that I must loop **from** A **to** B, so I can't have two intermediate integers and toss A and B into the right slots then have the same comparison and increment.  In the "A is larger" case I must decrement, and the opposite must increment.

I'm going to have potentially many nested loops that require this same setup, which means every if/else will have a function call, which I have to pass lots of variables through, or another if/else with another if/else etc.

Is there any tricky shortcut to avoid this without sacrificing much speed?  Function pointers and stuff in a tight, often repeated loop sound extremely painful to me.  Is there some crazy templates solution?

Comment: I guess you are not looking for optimizations that compilers already do for you, such as [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding), am I correct?

Comment: The `i` remembers the original value of `A`.

Comment: For what purpose? And it's not marked `const`. Conventionally one uses `i` to increment and leaves the original bounds untouched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
size_t const delta = size_t(A < B? 1 : -1);
size_t i = A;
for( ;; )
{
    // blah

    if( i == B ) { break; }
    i += delta;
}
```

Comment: This performs two less adds and uses one less variable than paddy's alternative, at the cost of being a bit uglier (although 2 parts of it can be integrated into the for loop).  I think `delta` should be `((A < B) << 1) - 1`.

Comment: Don't think this works as size_t(A < B? 1 : -1) evaluates to UINT_MAX for the -1 case.

Comment: sometimes, the simplest methods are the most effective ones!

Comment: @HerrJoebob I've tried it on all sorts of cases involving A and/or B being 0 and/or -1 along with other number pairings.  Being the max uint isn't a problem cause add/sub works the same for unsigned and 2s compliment, so it still acts like a -1.  Except in comparisons like < or >, but alf uses none of those in that context.

Answer (score 7):

My mistake, originally misinterpreting the question.

To make an inclusive loop from `A` to `B`, you have a tricky situation.  You need to loop one *past* B.  So you work out that value prior to your loop.  I've used the comma operator inside the `for` loop, but you can always put it outside for clarity.

```
int direction = (A < B) ? 1 : -1;
for( size_t i = A, iEnd = B+direction; i != iEnd; i += direction ) {
    ...
}
```

If you don't mind modifying `A` and `B`, you can do this instead (using `A` as the loop variable):

```
for( B+=direction, A != B; A += direction ) {

}
```

And I had a play around...  Don't know what the inlining rules are when it comes to function pointers, or whether this is any faster, but it's an exercise in any case. =)

```
inline const size_t up( size_t& val ) { return val++; }
inline const size_t down( size_t& val ) { return val--; }

typedef const size_t (*FnIncDec)( size_t& );

inline FnIncDec up_or_down( size_t A, size_t B )
{
    return (A <= B) ? up : down;
}

int main( void )
{
    size_t A = 4, B = 1;
    FnIncDec next = up_or_down( A, B );

    for( next(B); A != B; next(A) ) {
        std::cout << A << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

In response to this:

> This won't work for case A = 0, B = UINT_MAX (and vice versa)

That is correct.  The problem is that the initial value for `i` and `iEnd` become the same due to overflow.  To handle that, you would instead use a `do->while` loop.  That removes the initial test, which is redundant because you will *always* execute the loop body at least once...  By removing that first test, you iterate *past* the terminating condition the first time around.

```
size_t i = A;
size_t iEnd = B+direction;

do {
    // ...
    i += direction;
} while( i != iEnd );
```

Comment: That will cause me to loop from B to A in some cases.  It has to be A to B.

Comment: +1 good answer. and no, @paddy, you didn't make the alleged mistake. but you botched the continuation condition; i assume you will **fix it**!

Comment: I was wondering about using a pointer to the auto-increment or decrement functions for `size_t`, and whether that would be faster than using a `direction` variable...

Comment: That's the ticket, marked my answer to delete in favor of this one.

Comment: This won't work for case A = 0, B = UINT_MAX (and vice versa).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: No, he originally made the same mistake that I did. It's correct now (though I haven't checked all cases - errors like the one jrok reported may exist).

Comment: @paddy: Dereferencing a pointer to a function that performs arithmetic will never be faster than simply performing that arithmetic. This is a nice, clean, relatively simple solution.

Comment: @jrok Good point: if you ever wanted to do the entire range, you would need to use a `do -> while` loop instead.

Comment: You need to account for this, OP says his numbers are random.

Comment: @paddy: consider jrok's comment. at [http://ideone.com/8wkXvA](http://ideone.com/8wkXvA) i test your current code with start values A=0 and B=size_t(-1). it outputs nothing...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : Yep, I did.  Try the one at the bottom of the answer.  Maybe I should remove the rest.  I tend to rant a little sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

What are you going to do with the iterated value?

If this is going to be some index in an array, you should use the relevant `iterator` or `reverse_iterator` class, and implement your algorithms around these. Your code will be more robust, and easier to maintain or evolve. Besides, a lot of tools in the standard library are built using these interfaces.

Actually, even if you don't, you may implement an iterator class which returns its own index.

You can also use a little bit of metaprogramming magic to define how your iterator will behave according to the order of `A` and `B`.

Before going further, please consider that this would only work on **constant values** of `A` and `B`.

```
template <int A,int B>
struct ordered {
    static const bool value = A > B ? false: true;
};

template <bool B>
int pre_incr(int &v){
    return ++v;
}

template <>
int pre_incr<false>(int &v){
    return --v;
}

template <int A, int B>
class const_int_iterator : public iterator<input_iterator_tag, const int>
{
    int p;
  public:
    typedef const_int_iterator<A,B> self_type;
    const_int_iterator() : p(A) {}
    const_int_iterator(int s) : p(s) {}
    const_int_iterator(const self_type& mit) : p(mit.p) {}
    self_type& operator++() {pre_incr< ordered<A,B>::value >(p);return *this;}
    self_type operator++(int) {self_type tmp(*this); operator++(); return tmp;}
    bool operator==(const self_type& rhs) {return p==rhs.p;}
    bool operator!=(const self_type& rhs) {return p!=rhs.p;}
    const int& operator*() {return p;}
};


template <int A, int B> 
class iterator_factory {    
  public:
    typedef const_int_iterator<A,B> iterator_type;
    static iterator_type begin(){
        return iterator_type();
    }
    static iterator_type end(){
        return iterator_type(B);
    }
};
```

In the code above, I defined a barebone `iterator` class going accross the values from A to B. There's simple metaprogramming test to determine whether A and B are in ascending order, and pick the correct operator (`++` or `--`) to go through the values.

Finally, I also defined a simple factory class to hold `begin` and `end` iterators methods, Using this class let you have only one single point of declaration for your dependent type values A and B (I mean here that you only need to use A and B once for this container, and the iterators generated from there will be depending on these same A and B, thus simplifying code somewhat).

Here I provide a simple test program, outputing values from 20 to 11.

```
#define A 20
#define B 10

typedef iterator_factory<A,B> factory;

int main(){

   auto it = factory::begin();

   for (;it != factory::end();it++)
      cout << "iterator is : " << *it << endl;

}
```

There might better ways of doing this with the standard library though.

The issue of using `O` and `UINT_MAX` for `A` and `B` was brought up. I think it should be possible to handle these cases by overloading the templates using these particular values (left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: my answer is perhaps a bit contrived.

Comment: I certainly appreciate the effort, and with the overloads for edge cases and stuff it may be the fastest, I dunno.  But man, that's a lot to write for an integer loop!  Ah, and looking closer, my actual A and B are only known at runtime.

Comment: @user173342 I'm sure someone could come up with even more convoluted ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t A, B;

if (A > B) swap(A,B);  // Assuming A <= B, if not, make B to be A

for (size_t i = A; A <= B; ++A) ...
```

Comment: This will cause me to loop from the original value of B to A.  It always needs to be the original A to B.